# jQuery: How to create a menu and a submenu where the classes toggle on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have this JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zczwjdrw/7/

Menu 1:

When clicking on AAA it opens a menu. 
When clicking on BBB it opens an other menu and removes AAAs style back to default. When clicking on BBB again it closes the submenu but doesn't change back to default. How do I solve this?

Menu 2:

When clicking on a sub menu option - it colors it. when clicking on an other option - it doesn't remove the class from the previous element. and you can continue coloring all submenu options. What can be the solution for this? I have used the same functionality on jQuery as `.sidebar1`.

jQuery:

```
$('.sidebar1 a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active-sb1').siblings().removeClass('active-sb1');
});

$('.sidebar2 a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active-sb2').siblings().removeClass('active-sb2');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">

    <div class="sidebar1">

        <a href="ssb1" class="category" id="sb1" onclick="return false">
            <div>AAA</div>
        </a>

        <a href="ssb2" class="category" id="sb2" onclick="return false">
            <div>BBB</div>
        </a>

        <a href="ssb3" class="category" id="sb3" onclick="return false">
            <div>CCC</div>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar2" id="ssb1" style="display: none;">

        <div class="sb2-content">

            <h3>Choose Something:</h3>

        </div>

        <div class="sb2-menu">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="kas" onclick="return false">AAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="weekly_reports" onclick="return false">AAAAAAAAAAA</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="exceltower" onclick="return false">AAAAAAAAAAA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar2" id="ssb2" style="display: none;">

        <div class="sb2-content">

            <h3>Choose Something:</h3>

        </div>

        <div class="sb2-menu">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">BBBBBBBBBB</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">BBBBBBBBBB</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">BBBBBBBBBB</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar2" id="ssb3" style="display: none;">

        <div class="sb2-content">

            <h3>Choose Something:</h3>

        </div>

        <div class="sb2-menu">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CCCCCCCCC</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">CCCCCCCC</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">CCCCCCCC</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="main-content">

        <div class="user-bar">

        </div>

        <div class="content">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There is an error in your fiddle. Please resolve and update your question.

Comment: @RinoRaj updated. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In `.sidebar2` your `<a>` elements are inside a `<li>` so the `<a>` has no other siblings. But instead the parent  `<li>` has siblings.
So, you could try something like this:

```
$('.sidebar2 a').click(function() {
    var e = $(this);
    e.addClass('active-sb2');
    e.parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active-sb2');
});
```

And for your first problem, you could test if the element already has the class `active-sb1`, which means that the element is open, in which case you remove the class.

```
$('.sidebar1 > a').click(function() {
    var e = $(this);
    if (e.hasClass("active-sb1")) {
      e.removeClass('active-sb1');
    } else {
      e.addClass('active-sb1');
    }
    e.siblings().removeClass('active-sb1');
});
```

[Updated Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/a09bz4fv/)

Comment: oh, i didn't see the first question :) updated answer !